# Changing the onclick URL on Tumblr photosets

Tags: themes, tumblr

I have a tumblr blog embedded into my website (iframe) and want all clicks to open in a new tab to land on the post detail url (e.g. https://diestadtgaertner.tumblr.com/post/657405245299818496). I already adapted the template to get this working for most post types by exchanging the respective href variable with "https://diestadtgaertner.tumblr.com/post/{PostID}" and add target="_blank". However, I can't get this to work for the pictureset. Does anyone know how this might work?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks & best,
Torge

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your template so the photoset gets output into a normal div (I think the default is to load photosets inside an iframe themselves, which could be causing you issues.

This is the block from my tumblr template:

```
<ul>
...
    {block:Photoset}
        <li class="post photoset">
            {block:Photos}
                <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" {block:HighRes}style="display:none"{/block:HighRes} />
                {block:HighRes}
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres" />
                {/block:HighRes}
            {/block:Photos}
            {block:Caption}
                <div class="description">{Caption}</div>
            {/block:Caption}
            <p>
                <span class="icon-link ion-ios-infinite-outline"></span>
                <a href="{Permalink}" class="link">{block:Date}{DayOfMonthWithZero}.{MonthNumberWithZero}.{ShortYear}{/block:Date}</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    {/block:Photoset}
</ul>
```

In any case you could wrap the entire block in the Permalink href. Something like:

```
<ul>
...
    {block:Photoset}
        <li class="post photoset">
            <a href="{Permalink}"> // this permalink href now wraps the entire content of the post. 
                {block:Photos}
                    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" {block:HighRes}style="display:none"{/block:HighRes} />
                    {block:HighRes}
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="highres" />
                    {/block:HighRes}
                {/block:Photos}
                {block:Caption}
                    <div class="description">{Caption}</div>
                {/block:Caption}
            </a>
        </li>
    {/block:Photoset}
</ul>
```

The issue now is that the default click links for the images inside this post (if they exist) will no longer function normally.

It is difficult to test this without the link to your site, but I think updating your tumblr template first should hopefully give you the result you are after, but of course I would recommend a backing up your code.